# Share static lazy-initialized object containing `Rc` refs among multiple threads with `thread_local!` and `OnceCell`

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, static, rust, lazy-initialization

I have split my tests into several, similar sections. Within each section, results are compared against a static test string, written in a dedicated tested language (here called `dum`) and parsed with [`pest`](https://pest.rs/).

---

Here is the global structure of my MWE.

```
$ tree
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   └── main.rs
└── tests
    ├── dum.pest
    ├── section_1.rs
    └ .. imagine more similar sections here.
```

- `Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
...
edition = "2018"

[dev-dependencies]
pest = "*"
pest_derive = "*"
once_cell = "*"
lazy_static = "*"
```

- `main.rs` only contains `fn main() {}`.
- `dum.pest` is a dummy `any = { ANY* }`.
- `section_1.rs` preamble is:

```rust
use pest_derive::Parser;
use pest::{iterators::Pairs, Parser};

// Compile dedicated grammar.
#[derive(Parser)]
#[grammar = "../tests/dum.pest"]
pub struct DumParser;

// Here is the static test string to run section 1 against.
static SECTION_1: &'static str = "Content to parse for section 1.";

// Type of the result expected to be globally available in the whole test section.
type ParseResult = Pairs<'static, Rule>;
```

---

Now, my first naive attempt to make the parse result available to all test function was:

```rust
// Naive lazy_static! attempt:
use lazy_static::lazy_static;
lazy_static! {
    static ref PARSED: ParseResult = {
        DumParser::parse(Rule::any, &*SECTION_1).expect("Parse failed.")
    };
}
#[test]
fn first() {
    println!("1: {:?} parsed to {:?}", &*SECTION_1, *PARSED);
}
#[test]
fn second() {
    println!("2: {:?} parsed to {:?}", &*SECTION_1, *PARSED);
}
```

This does not compile. According to [`pest`](https://github.com/pest-parser/pest/issues/400#issuecomment-513039043), it's because they use inner `Rc` references that cannot be safely shared among threads, and I think `cargo test` does spin a new thread for each `#[test]` function.

The suggested solution involves the use of `thread_local!` and `OnceCell`, but I cannot figure it out. The following two attempts:

```rust
// Naive thread_local! attempt:
thread_local! {
    static PARSED: ParseResult = {
        println!(" + + + + + + + PARSING! + + + + + + + "); // /!\ SHOULD APPEAR ONLY ONCE!
        DumParser::parse(Rule::any, &*SECTION_1).expect("Parse failed.")
    };
}
#[test]
fn first() {
    PARSED.with(|p| println!("1: {:?} parsed to {:?}", &*SECTION_1, p));
}
#[test]
fn second() {
    PARSED.with(|p| println!("2: {:?} parsed to {:?}", &*SECTION_1, p));
}
```

and

```rust
// Naive OnceCell attempt:
use once_cell::sync::OnceCell;
thread_local! {
static PARSED: OnceCell<ParseResult> = {
    println!(" + + + + + + + PARSING! + + + + + + + "); // /!\ SHOULD APPEAR ONLY ONCE!
        let once = OnceCell::new();
        once.set(DumParser::parse(Rule::any, &*SECTION_1).expect("Parse failed."))
        .expect("Already set.");
        once
    };
}
#[test]
fn first() {
    PARSED.with(|p| println!("1: {:?} parsed_to {:?}", &*SECTION_1, p.get().unwrap()));
}
#[test]
fn second() {
    PARSED.with(|p| println!("2: {:?} parsed_to {:?}", &*SECTION_1, p.get().unwrap()));
}
```

Both compile and run fine. But the output of `cargo test -- --nocapture`
suggests that the parsing is actually done once for each test function:

```
running 2 tests
 + + + + + + + PARSING! + + + + + + +
 + + + + + + + PARSING! + + + + + + +
1: "Content to parse for section 1." parsed_to [Pair { rule: any, span: Span { str: "Content to parse for section 1.", start: 0, end: 31 }, inner: [] }]
2: "Content to parse for section 1." parsed_to [Pair { rule: any, span: Span { str: "Content to parse for section 1.", start: 0, end: 31 }, inner: [] }]
test first ... ok
test second ... ok

test result: ok. 2 passed; 0 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured; 0 filtered out
```

This reveals that I have failed in both my attempts.

What is wrong with these approaches?
How do I make the parsing occur only once per section?

Comment: If I understand the issue correctly, there is no reasonable way to get what you want. `Pairs` cannot be shared across threads, so you must make a new one for each test. Also, I'm not sure it would even do what you want, since it's an iterator that would be shared across the tests, and you'd get the items in a nondeterministic order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why isn't `lazy_static!` suitable?

Whether `cargo test` spins up a new thread per test or not is actually irrelevant.

A `static` variable is global, and thus *potentially* shared between threads, thus even if no thread is ever spawned, it must be `Sync`.

And since `Rc` is not `Sync` (cannot be shared between threads), this cannot work.

#### Why isn't `thread_local!` suitable?

There is one `thread_local!` variable per thread, as the name suggests.

The code within `thread_local!` is actually not run immediately upon thread-creation; as the variable is lazily instantiated on first access.

#### How do I make parsing occur only once per section?

Don't use the output of `pest` directly.

If you post-process the output of `pest` and create a structure that is `Sync` out of it, then you can store it with `lazy_static` and it will only be parsed once.

Actually, you could go further and avoid `lazy_static` entirely. If you can express the structure in a purely `const` way, then you could use a `build.rs` script or procedural macro to transform the string into a model at compile-time. For tests, though, this may not be worth the effort.

Comment: I am not actually sure whether a thread is spawned for each test, or if a thread-pool is used with one thread per core. This could be determined empirically by creating 2x or 4x as many tests as you have cores and count how many times parsing occurs.

Comment: I think I understand better now. The most reasonable seems to post-process the parse output into something `Sync`. I'll give it a try. Thank you for this very clear answer :)

Comment: Interestingly, the cost of post-processing the output of `pest` in `lazy_static` is to somehow *rewrite the grammar structure* entirely by hand so as to convert it into anything `Sync`. That is too much duplication to maintain in a `test` procedure. I'm dropping it in favour of multiple parsing passes. Anyway, my goal was to learn something. I did. Thank you :)